# tikz won't plot x*sqrt(1-x^2) until the end

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot x*sqrt(1-x^2), but tikz seemingly won't plot the function until the end.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-0.1,0)--(1.5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.1)--(0,1) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[domain=0:1,smooth,thick,variable=\x,samples=100] 
plot (\x,{\x*(sqrt(1-\x^2))});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How can I prolong the line to reach x-axis? Thanks!

Comment: This is most likely rounding error. Try different parametrization. Eg. (cos(t), cos(t)sin(t)). Or you may cheat by `\draw plot (x, y) -- (1,0);`

Comment: It works fine. Thank you!

Comment: TikZ connects points (from `samples`, on the x-axis) on the graph. In this case, the graph is almost vertical near `x=1`. So you can do as @Symbel 1 suggested above, or you can increase samples `\draw[domain=0:1,smooth,thick,variable=\x,samples=5000] 
plot (\x,{\x*(sqrt(1-\x^2))});
`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.